# In analysis of randomized load balancing allocation (using Chernoff bounds), how do you get upperbound on $\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}$?

Tags: probability, logarithms

This question is from Kelinberg Tardos "Algorithm Design" p. 761. I just don't understand a step they take in their analysis of a randomized load balancing algorithm. I asked my supervisor, who thought it was just a typo. This could be true, but we need something for the bound. I've attached a photo of the relevant page. [image: p761 bottom of Kleinberg Tardos Algorithm Design]

I have two questions:

1. How do they get the inequality $\log \log n > 766 \log x$?
2. And on the next line how to get  $\frac{\log n}{\log \log n} \leq x$

If it is a typo, how to get upper bound on $\gamma (n)$?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the $766$ just shouldn't be there.

Note that for $x>e$ we have $n=x^x > e^x$, implying that $\log n > x$ and $\log \log n > \log x$.

Taking the equation $x \log x = \log n$ and dividing the left side by $\log x$ and the right by $\log \log n$ then gives 
$$x > \frac{\log n}{\log \log n}.$$

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right. Thank you. I clearly misunderstood the first time I asked for help.